# React Native - Swipe on active screen cause the ghost swiping on the behind screen

Tags: react-native

I've put a FlatList on a parent screen. On click on the list item will popup another child screen. I'm using StackNavigator of course to stack them. Right after I close the child screen and go back to parent screen, the list item which I click on previously is gone because the list has been scrolled. I don't want to just disable the scroll on the list of the behind screen, which also I can't find out how to do it. But also I want to totally disable any gesture on behind screen, like how it supposed to be naturally.

This is the simplest how you may replicate the error. Thank you in advance for all your help

App.js

```
const App = createStackNavigator({
    Test1 : { screen : Test1 },
    Test2 : { screen : Test2 },
});

export default App;
```

Test.js

```
class Test1 extends Component{

    render() {
        var test = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) test.push(i);
        return (<FlatList
            data = {test}
            renderItem = {
                ({item}) => <Button 
                    onPress = () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Test2') 
                    title = {'' + item}/>
            }
        />);
    }
}

class Test2 extends Component{

    render() {
        return (<View></View>);
    }
}

module.exports = {Test1, Test2};
```

Comment: If you post your code will help, I thnk.

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo I have included the code. Thank you sir for helping

Comment: Sorry. It's actually genymotion. Only happen when you scroll using mousewheel. Not sure whether it's genymotion's bug or react native's layout structure causes genymotion to become kooky

Comment: yes, that happen when use scroll.